# Weird SWD debug port behaviour

Tags: stm32, ground, interference, swd

Today I have started to encounter strange problems with SWD debugging.

The debug only works if I keep my finger on the SWD pins. To be more interesting I have the same problem with the boards I was working in the past without any problems. All Vdd and Vss are connected correctly - checked many times.

I am trying to sort this problem for two days and have run out of the fresh ideas what actually can cause this problem.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: puuuuuh. Hmmmm. First of all: mechanical problems. are your solder joints and connectors intact? then: What's the ground used by your SWD programmer? Is it *definitely* the same as the the one of your STM32? Then: EMI – maybe your finger is absorbing RF noise, but that would be a peculiar kind of luck. Is there something switching very high currents or very fast on your board/in your vicinity? Got an oscilloscope to probe the SWD lines during (non-)operation?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Nothing. As I wrote I try to sort out this problem for two days. Strange that my other boards behave the same now as well. (two different debug probe tested). I have tired literally everything.

Comment: That makes the EMI problems more likely. What about that oscilloscope? Do you have one, how much bandwidth does it muster?

Comment: To be more interesting the problem is only with the stm32F3 boards. All other work OK

Comment: Lines are clear. No noise

Comment: how does the SWD serial signal shape look like? How sharp are the edges? At which speed are you operating? Can you add an oscilloscope plot to your question?

Comment: Software/firmware problems? Flash the boards with the last known good version of your software, e.g. from a week ago. Was anything changed in the development environment, like OS updates, new drivers installed, SWD probe firmware?

Comment: @berendi even fresh macros behave the same. To be honest never had it before

Comment: (assuming you've meant micros) then we might assume that the boards are fine. Look elsewhere.

Comment: Change the *entire* hardware environment. Start from the obvious like cabling, debugger probe, power supply, outlet, PC. Try it with a laptop on battery power. The board on battery power if possible. Move to another room or building. Change your clothes. Not kidding, happened me once. Change *yourself*, i.e. ask someone to start the debugger while you step out of the room.

Comment: @berendi already tried it. And also on the board additionally I have wired GND together, VDD-eses, tried to pull up or down SWDIO & SWDCLK. I have mesured all the voltages, checked if all the micro Vdds and Vsses are connected and hundreds of other things. To be honest I start to be a bit desperate.

Comment: Are these boards of your own design? Have you checked any pull resistors attached to SWDIO? Looks like you should have a pull-up on that pin. Touching it might act in such way if the resistor is not present.

Comment: Btw, that pull-up should be around 100kohms.

Comment: @FilipeNicoli pull-up does not help

Comment: Your boards have embedded debugging hardware like TI's Launchpads or are you using a dedicated debugger/programmer hardware?

Comment: Do you have good grounding?  Ideal would be a twisted pair for each of the signals.  Also, you can try lowering the clock rate.  I have seen issues where you get strange problems at 3MHz, and things work fine at 2 MHz.

Comment: @crj11 as I wrote before I have tried all the trivial solutions. BTW connecting the oscilloscope probe to the SWCLK helps.

Comment: @FilipeNicoli dedicated

Comment: @MarcusMüller when I connect the scope (it is enough to the SWDSCK line it starts to work. Edges are perfect

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same bizarre issue with an STM32L4 on a small custom 2-layer board with an MCP25625.

Adding a piece of wire or short alligator cable to the ground and/or SWD pins remedies the problem.

My theory is there's RF energy/noise, and the added wire is acting like an antenna and transmitting the RF energy rather than letting it reflect internally... perhaps I'm completely wrong but I'm at a loss otherwise.

Will be switching to a 4-layer (signal/GND/GND/signal) board to mitigate noise and tightly control return currents. I will report back on whether this remedies the problem.

Comment: I have the solution - SWD on some chips is not pulled does/up (depending on the pin). Adding resistor on the boards solves this problem

Comment: Thanks for the update. I also found this out; the pull up/down helped but did not fix the issue. I will report back once I figure it out.